# How to start a consistently updated Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, phpmyadmin

I have the longitude and latitude of vehicles and other things that are going to be constantly updating and would like to use Google Maps API v3 to keep track of them.

I don't believe my current method of importing these locations (importing into a Fusion Table which then geocodes it) is efficient or allow for Google Maps to grab data.

I have basic experience in php and Javascript, so my idea is to use phpMyAdmin to keep the database and have Google Maps pull data from there, but I have no idea where to start or how to have phpMyAdmin with a consistent dataflow.  Could someone give me a starting point or perhaps offer a better solution?

This example shows a end result which is a still image.  I'm not sure if this will get the results I want.
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: Possible duplicate of any number of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-maps-api-3]+moving+markers+from+database

Comment: Moving markers is definitely my goal here, but it seems these users already have a updating MySql server. If I try for 'Update' in the search bar, it finds the sql command UPDATE.  For now, my source is static and unchanging in the database.  I want that to be an automated thing for every 30 minutes, more or less.